# xpath query omit results with parent tag

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I'm fairly new to xpath so seeking some help with a pattern to match the following. My current attempt isn't matching what I would expect.

```
//text()[1][contains(.,'wordToMatch') and not(self::a)]
```

As i'm sure you can see from the pattern above, i'm a noob.

Sample payload 1:

```
<p>Sample 1 <a href="shouldNotMatchWrappedInA">wordToMatch</a> some 
random text 
to not be matched followed by wordToMatch, this should work.</p>
```

Expected Result 1:

```
wordToMatch (Not the one inside of a' tags but the following one)
```

Sample payload 2:

```
<p>Sample 2 <a href="shouldNotMatchWrappedInA">wordToMatch</a> some 
random text to not be matched followed by <b>wordToMatch</b> this
should work.</p>
```

Expected Result 2:

```
wordToMatch (The one inside of the b' tags)
```

Sample payload 3:

```
<p>Sample 3 <a href="shouldNotMatchWrappedInA">wordToMatch</a> some 
random text to not be matched followed by wordToMatch followed by
further occurrences of wordToMatch which should not be matched.</p>
```

Expected Result 3:

```
wordToMatch (The second occurrence of the term)
```

Expected results for all 3 payloads is the first occurrence of the term **wordToMatch** which is **NOT** wrapped inside of an 'a' Tag.

The end language that will implement this pattern is Java.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not clear from the question what you're after exactly, adding *exact* expected output for each sample will clears things up, I think. Anyway, based on current information, consider the following XPath which will match any element where inner text is exactly equals 'wordToMatch', and the element itself is not an `<a>` element :

```
//*[.='wordToMatch'][not(self::a)]
```

This will return `b` element in the 2nd case and none for other cases. If you want to relax the matching return the text node (instead of parent element), this will do:

```
//*[not(self::a)]/text()[contains(.,'wordToMatch')]
```

**UPDATE**:

In XPath 2.0 or above you can use `for` construct :

```
for $t in //*[not(self::a)]/text()[contains(.,'wordToMatch')]
return 'wordToMatch'
```

**<kbd>[`xpatheval demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/_VvBxT44o)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i've taken it onboard and updated the question.

Comment: @CoDemystifiedJavaFx very late response, sorry. Based on the updated question, I think the best XPath 1.0 can do is to return the relevant text node i.e the one that contains 'wordToMatch' (so, the 2nd XPath in this question, probably with additional `[1]` at the end if you want to return only the first matched node from each parent element). Then you can post-process XPath output in Java i.e for each text node return string "wordToMatch"

Comment: @CoDemystifiedJavaFx if you can use XPath 2.0 or above, then you may want to try the updated answer